# Calling VBScript Procedure results type mismatch error

Tags: com, vbscript, variant

One of my COM object has a following member which returns byte array and its lengh in the second argument.

```
HRESULT GetBinaryData([out] VARIANT *pVal, [out] long *pLen);
```

FYI,

```
**Part of implementation is as follows:**
....
VariantInit(pVal);
pVal->vt = VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY;
SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
rgsabound[0].lLbound = ARRAY_LBOUND;
rgsabound[0].cElements = (ULONG)len;
pVal->parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, rgsabound);
....
```

I am trying to invoke this memeber in VBScript but failed in all of my trials. Here is my vbscript code snippet:

```
Set op = CreateObject("myserver")
dim bytearray()
op.GetBinaryData bytearray, bytearray_len
```

But at line 3, Type mismatch error is encountered...

How can I get the result from the procedure into my vbscript variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `retval` at the COM level:

```
HRESULT GetBinaryData([out, retval] VARIANT *pVal);
```

since the return value is a `SAFEARRAY` your existing C++ will still work. In this case, `SAFEARRAY` is a sufficient return to give the caller both the array and the length. i.e. your C++ code remains as-is.

Your VBScript code becomes:

```
Option Explicit
Set op = CreateObject("myserver")
Dim byteArray, lenArray
byteArray = op.GetBinaryData()
lenArray = UBound(byteArray) - LBound(byteArray) + 1
```

Although you can only have one `retval` by means of `SAFEARRAY` or an equivalent object (e.g. `IXMLDOMDocument`) you can package a number of return values for VBScript.